# What is the meaning of the integral of $X_{s,r} \otimes dX_r$?

Tags: integration, tensor-products

I found this when reading through [these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3014), on page 3.

$X$ is a function with continuous derivatives up to some order $\alpha$, and $X_{s,r}$ is shorthand for $X_r - X_s$.

What does
$$ \int\limits_s^t X_{s,r} \otimes dX_r $$ 
mean?

Comment: $\mathbb{X}_{s,t} \colon=\int_s^t X_{s,t} \otimes dX_r$ is a definition for a rough path on regularity structures.

Comment: Yes but what does it mean to take the integral of the tensor product between a function ($X_{s,r}$) and the derivative of a function ($dX_r$)?